# How to get vue slot property in JSX?

Tags: vue.js, jsx, slot

I write a child component used template syntax, child component has a slot that transmits 'item' property to parent component, but parent component use JSX syntax, now I have trouble how to get 'item' property in JSX. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```html
// child.vue
<template>
  <Autocomplete>
    <template slot-scope="{ item }">
      <slot :item="item" />
    </template>
  </Autocomplete>
</template>
```

```js
// parent.vue
export default {
  render () {
    return (
      <Child>
        <template slot-scope='{item}'>
          <span>{item}</span> // item is not defined 
        </template>
      </Child>
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

You can pass the slots as a `scopedSlots` prop (Vue 2) with a `default` function (representing the default slot). Note this is especially needed for non-default named slots (e.g., `"mySlot"` as shown in the example):

```js
export default {
  render() {
    return (
      <Child
        {
          ...{
            scopedSlots: {
              default: ({ item }) => <span>{ item.foo }</span>,
              mySlot: ({ myProp }) => <h1>{ myProp }</h1>,
            }
          }
        }
      />
    )
  }
}
```

Or you can pass a default-slot rendering method within the `<Child>` body:

```js
export default {
  render() {
    return (
      <Child>
        { ({ item }) => <span>{ item.foo }</span> }
      </Child>
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this?

```
// child.vue
<template>
  <Autocomplete>
    <template v-slot="{ item }">
      <slot :item="item" />
    </template>
  </Autocomplete>
</template>
```

And in the parent component:

```
// JSX
{
  render () {
    return (
      <Child>
        <template v-slot="{ item }">
          <span>{{item}}</span> // item is not defined 
        </template>
      </Child>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: this way is also not work, 'item' property in JSX is undefined, thanks.